# How can I bind the click event in ItemsControl of UWP?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I wanna to make a HamburgerMenu.and here is XAML.

```
<SplitView Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <SplitView.Content>
                    <ListView>
                        <ItemsControl x:Name="NavItemsControl">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel></StackPanel>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Button>
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Text="{Binding Icon}"></TextBlock>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}" Grid.Column="1"></TextBlock>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Button>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </ListView>
                </SplitView.Content>
            </SplitView>
```

And here is code behind:

```
public class NavItems : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        string _Icon;
        public string Icon
        {
            set
            {
                _Icon = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Icon");
            }
            get
            {
                return _Icon;
            }
        }
        string _Content;
        public string Content
        {
            set
            {
                _Content = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Content");

            }
            get
            {
                return _Content;
            }
        }            

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

After setted the ItemSource of NavItemsControl,I can easily bind the property such as Icon or Content.The only problem is I want to bind the click event of 
 the Button but I don't know how to bind it.
I tried using delegate to bind the click event,but it no works and report an error.
Would you please to help me ?
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before we get to your question, let's first fix your XAML. You are using a `ListView` to wrap a `ItemsControl`, this is unnecessary. Actually, `ListView` itself inherits from `ItemsControl` and is basically a much more powerful version of it. In your case, a `ItemsControl` should be sufficient, so you can safely remove the `ListView` wrapper.

Since you have used a `Button` inside your template, you can create a `ClickCommand` (of type `ICommand`) in `NavItems` and bind the `Button`'s `Command` property to it.

```
<Button Command="{Binding ClickCommand}" />
```

There are tons of resources on the Internet where you can find an `ICommand` implementation, have a look at how it's done in the [UWP Toolkit](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/tree/71f3aaca4a603b19b6bf8de463606d33763d07fe/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.SampleApp/Common).

---

**Side Note**

I personally don't like using `SelectionChanged` because it's a *data-driven* event that can be triggered by data changes. This could be unpredictable and error-prone. Besides, you cannot re-select the same item unless you manually reset the `SelectedIndex`. A button `Click` (or `ItemClick` from `ListView`) is an *input-driven* event which can only (in most cases) be invoked by a user action, which rarely gives you any side-effects.

Comment: I am a beginer of UWP,thanks very much for your advice of Listview.What's more, I agree with your opinion of the SelectionChanged.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In order to register an event for you button click you need to add and define the Selection Changed event of the ListView. So your code should be something like this :

```
<SplitView Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <SplitView.Content>
                    <ListView x:Name="itemListView" SelectionChanged="ItemListView_SelectionChanged">
                        <ItemsControl x:Name="NavItemsControl">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel></StackPanel>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Button>
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Text="{Binding Icon}"></TextBlock>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}" Grid.Column="1"></TextBlock>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Button>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </ListView>
                </SplitView.Content>
            </SplitView>
```

C# Code behind should look something like this :

```
private void ItemListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
      if(itemListView.SelectedItem!=null){
         Debug.WriteLine(itemListView.SelectedIndex + " Index selected");
         // More logic here 
      }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do it with ICommand,but the code look likes so ugly.Just for reference only.

```
<SplitView Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <SplitView.Content>
                    <ItemsControl x:Name="NavItemsControl">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <StackPanel></StackPanel>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Command="{Binding ClickCommand}" Padding="10,20" Background="Transparent">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Text="{Binding Icon}" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="20,0,0,0"></TextBlock>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Button>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </SplitView.Content>
            </SplitView>
```

Code behind:

```
public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            NavItems.ClickVoidDelegate CD = new NavItems.ClickVoidDelegate(()=> { Debug.WriteLine("123"); });
            List<NavItems> NavItemsList = new List<NavItems>()
            {
                new NavItems(){
                    Icon="\xE166",Content="Open",ClickCommand=new NavItems.ClickCommandClass(CD)
                }
            };

            NavItemsControl.ItemsSource = NavItemsList;
        }
public class NavItems : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            string _Icon;
            public string Icon
            {
                set
                {
                    _Icon = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Icon");

                }
                get
                {
                    return _Icon;
                }
            }
            string _Content;
            public string Content
            {
                set
                {
                    _Content = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Content");

                }
                get
                {
                    return _Content;
                }
            }
            ClickCommandClass _ClickCommand;
            public ClickCommandClass ClickCommand
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
            public class ClickCommandClass : ICommand
            {
                public ClickCommandClass(ClickVoidDelegate ClickVoid)
                {
                    _ClickVoid = ClickVoid;
                }
                ClickVoidDelegate _ClickVoid;
                public void Execute(object parameter)
                {
                    if (_ClickVoid != null)
                    {
                        _ClickVoid();
                    }
                }
                public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
            }
            public delegate void ClickVoidDelegate();
            protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
            {
                PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
                if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        }
```